# How can I read from STDIN while stepwise execution with phpdbg

Tags: phpdbg

Debugging a php script with phpdbg, how can I read from some data from STDIN ?

I am debugging a php script foo.php.
foo.php reads from a line from STDIN when executed.
I want to stepwise execute it with phpdbg.

I tried that

```
$ phpdbg foo.php
phpdbg> run < data.txt
```

but it doesn't work. data.txt contains some lines that I want to read from STDIN.
Any suggestions?

Comment: phpdbg maintainer here; simple answer: no way to do this yet. … I've put this on the list of things to do soon, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your question, I've just implemented that in phpdbg. It will be available with 7.0.13.

For reference, the relevant git commit: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=9d537951c5e4af5e453dd4d60e74dad039856b80

The syntax is exactly like you proposed:

```
r arg1 arg2 < file
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much!
I'm looking forward to using this new feature!